# Matching words that are not inside any comment with regular expressions and Unix tools

Tags: regex, sed

How can I use sed, awk or something else to match for the occurences of the word `type`, where the lines containing `type` do not have any occurences of `!` before the occurence of `type`? Then replace `type` with something else?

So I am asking to match the occurences of word `type` which aren't inside Fortran 90 comments.

**EDIT**

- Multiple occurences of the word on the same line, before `!` should also be replaced.
- `!` does not function as comment character when inside single or double quotes, so occurences following `"!"`, `'!'`, `"'!'"` should also be replaced. I think this makes the task quite complicated.
- Words that contain `type` should not be changed, like `footype`.

Possible solution:

```
awk -F '!' -v OFS='!' '{ gsub("\\<type\\>", "replacement", $1) } 1' file
```

seems to solve the issue, but it still cannot handle the `!` inside quotes.

**Minimal example**

```
  type = 2 +type
  type type 
  lel = "!" type
  lel = '!' type
  lel = "'!'" type
  ! type=2
type
footype
```

Should turn into:

```
  replacement = 2 +replacement
  replacement replacement 
  lel = "!" replacement
  lel = '!' replacement
  lel = "'!'" replacement
  ! type=2
replacement
footype
```

Comment: `grep -F type sourceFile | grep -vE '!.*type'`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yup, that works. But I made a mistake, I was thinking of sed apparently. I updated the question.

Comment: Pardon an ignorant question; is there any way a line could contain `!` in such a context that it does not constitute a comment? (Inside a string, perhaps?)

Comment: @tripleee not ignorant, in fact good question. ``!``s inside double or single quotes are ignored.

Comment: That makes the task a whole lot more complex. Use a proper Fortran parser.

Comment: Indeed. But I feel like it can still be done in awk or sed, by specifying ``!``s that are not surrounded by double or single quotes.

Comment: -1 for insisting on a regex solution, but above all for changing the problem statement, multiple times even.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, you have right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Given the new constraints, and assuming your comment !'s are always encapsulated by spaces and the quoted !'s are not, a minor change to tripleee's answer would work:
*Include the encapsulating spaces in the field separator.*

**Test case:** ( with random occurrences of the conditions thrown in )

```
 odd= (/ '!'1,3,5,7,9 /)  ! array assignment
 even=(/ 2,4,6,8,10 /) ! array assignment
 a=1"'!'"write         ! testing: write
 b=2
 c=a+b+e      ! element by element assignment
 c(odd)=c(even)-1  ! can use arrays of indices on both sides
 d=sin(c)     ! element by element application of intrinsics
 write(*,*)d
 write(*,*)abs(d)  ! many intrinsic functions are generic 
 write(*,*)abs(d)write  ! many intrinsic functions are generic
 write(c=a+b+e)      ! element by write element assignment
 write(*,*)abs("!"d)write  ! many intrinsic functions are generic
```

**Command and output:**

```
$ awk -F ' ! ' -v OFS=' ! ' '{ gsub("write", "replacement", $1) } 1' type

 odd= (/ '!'1,3,5,7,9 /)  ! array assignment
 even=(/ 2,4,6,8,10 /) ! array assignment
 a=1"'!'"replacement         ! testing: write
 b=2
 c=a+b+e      ! element by element assignment
 c(odd)=c(even)-1  ! can use arrays of indices on both sides
 d=sin(c)     ! element by element application of intrinsics
 replacement(*,*)d
 replacement(*,*)abs(d)  ! many intrinsic functions are generic 
 replacement(*,*)abs(d)replacement  ! many intrinsic functions are generic
 replacement(c=a+b+e)      ! element by write element assignment
 replacement(*,*)abs("!"d)replacement  ! many intrinsic functions are generic
```

Comment: I think this does not work for multiple occurences of the word on the same line.

Comment: You're right. Hadn't had any occurrence of that in the fortran code I'd googled, and given the new criteria in the question, I've updated the answer to something AWK based.

Comment: I will have to choose tripleee's answer, because he posted that answer first.

Comment: Yarr, I give him credit as well. Already upvoted his; just throwing in the " ! " amendment for future readers, since my rep isn't high enough to comment on his.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
awk -F '!' -v OFS='!' '{ gsub("type", "replacement", $1) } 1' file
```

Using `-F '!'` turns the field separator into exclamation mark; so the first field is any text before the first separator, and we replace `type` globally within this field only. (The lone `1` is a shorthand idiom for printing all lines; `OFS` is the output field separator, which inelegantly needs to be set separately to preserve the input field separator.)

Comment: Could you accept my edit about matching the full word?

Answer (score 1):

Here I do test for position using `awk`

```
cat file
This!hastypeinit
her are more type do
thistypemay also go
what type ! i have here
There must ! this type be
```

```
awk 'index($0,"!")>index($0,"type") || !index($0,"!") {sub(/type/,"****")}1' file
This!hastypeinit
her are more **** do
this****may also go
what **** ! i have here
There must ! this type be
```

---

Or use the same `regex` as Sintrinsic:

```
awk '/^[^!]*type/ {sub(/type/,"****")}1' file
This!hastypeinit
her are more **** do
this****may also go
what **** ! i have here
There must ! this type be
```

Comment: I think this does not work for multiple occurences of the word on the same line.

Comment: @nrs You can then change `sub` to `gsub`. It will then change all `type` if it has no `!` exist in front.